# Generate session key based on PUBLICKEYBLOB / PRIVATEKEYBLOB

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cryptoapi

My code looks like this, I traced each undefined method here to the functions called with relevant arguments included.

I have a hard time wrapping my head around the API. So what I have here is that I can generate public/private keys, and I can generate **a** session key, but how can I generate a session key based on the public key?
What am I missing/assuming (wrong) here?

```
void Crypto::GenerateKeyPair( Buffer& publicKey, Buffer& privateKey ) throw(WinError)
{
    /* CryptAcquireContext ( PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) */
    CryptContext context = CryptoProviders::NewContext(PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
    /* CryptGenKey( AT_KEYEXCHANGE, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &key) */
    CryptKey key = context.GenerateKeyExchangePair(); 
    /* CryptExportKey( PUBLICKEYBLOB, pPub); */
    key.ExportPublicKey(publicKey);
    /* CryptExportKey( PRIVATEKEYBLOB, pPriv); */
    key.ExportPrivateKey(privateKey);
}


void Crypto::GenerateSessionKey( Buffer& sessionKey ) throw(WinError)
{
    /* CryptAcquireContext ( PROV_RSA_FULL, 0 ) */
    CryptContext context = CryptoProviders::NewContext(PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
    /* CryptGenKey( CALG_RC4, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE ) */
    /* CryptGetUserKey( AT_KEYEXCHANGE ) */
    /* CryptExportKey( SIMPLEBLOB ) */
    context.GenerateSessionKey(sessionKey);
}

void Crypto::EncryptData( const Buffer& publicKey, const Buffer& plaintext, Buffer& encrypted )
{
    /* CryptAcquireContext ( PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) */
    CryptContext hProvider(PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
    /* CryptImportKey( 0 ) */
    CryptKey key = hProvider.ImportKey(publicKey);
    /* CryptEncrypt() */
    key.Encrypt(plaintext, encrypted);

}

void Crypto::DecryptData( const Buffer& privateKey, const Buffer& encrypted, Buffer& plaintext )
{
    /* CryptAcquireContext ( PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) */
    CryptContext hProvider(PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
    /* CryptImportKey( 0 ) */
    CryptKey key = hProvider.ImportKey(privateKey);
    /* CryptDecrypt() */
    key.Decrypt(encrypted, plaintext);
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session key is a **symmetric key** (meaning same key used for encryption and decryption). It is EXCHANGED with the other node secretly *using* asymmetric key pair (public and private keys).

So you *do not generate session key* from public key, rather you come up with a session key on your own (or better yet negotiate through some protocol as pointed out in comment e.g. D-H key exchange) and **encrypt that using the other node's public key and send**. So only the other side can discover the session key because ONLY it can decrypt data using its private key.

Reading [reasons for using session keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_key) would help

Comment: Or negotiated independently by both sides using a key agreement protocol.

Comment: So in case of a network stream, I would encrypt the session key with the other party's public key, and they would share this key to encrypt network traffic. And periodically exchange new session keys periodically if the connection is long lived (and each new connection generates a new session key). And in the case of say encrypting a file, I would just use the public key to encrypt it?

Comment: One exchange (several packets depending upon the protocol of negotiation)in the beginning would end up with both parties knowing the session key. All subsequent packets between the two nodes would use the session key for encryption and decryption. This is irrespective of whether you have a file or whatever to send. On network level it is just packets, the moment you attempt establishing a secure connection with the other end (SSL, IPsec), the first step would be key exchange using Asymmetric methods (which is more computation intensive and hence done only once per session).

Comment: As already asked above, why are you trying to do this manually? using any encryption api such as open ssl would do that for you.

Comment: Hobby project of mine, explore various WinAPI's and create C++ class wrappers for them. Increases my knowledge by using C++ and get to be on friendly terms with the bucketloads of WinAPIs. Sorry it's not that exciting :P

Comment: @CS On the contrary, it's *too* exciting. Cryptography is hard, and not for amateurs.

Comment: That's a fair reasoning and a cool area. I suggested looking at existing open source projects too such as openssl, openvpn, kame or racoon2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. And yes, cryptography is hard, and for serious use one should use existing projects that have been vetted by crypto professionals.